# add div element beside table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a problem, i am newbie in jquery

i have a table, and i want to add a div tag at beside of table

this is my code i try:

table :

```
<body>
<table id='menu_samping'>
    <tr>
        <td>Fashion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Electronik</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Food</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Accessories</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="last">Health</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

and this my jquery and css code:

```
    #menu_samping{
        width: 120px;
        border-spacing: 0px;

    }
    #menu_samping tr{
        height: 40px;
    }
    #menu_samping td{
        padding-left: 5px;
        background-color: #4b4b4b;
        border-bottom: groove #202020 2px;
        color : white;
    }
    #menu_samping td:hover{
        color : #d98d00;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #menu_samping td.last{
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
    }
    #testElem{
        border: 1px black solid;
        background: white;
        height: 500px;
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #segitiga{
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 4px 5px 4px 0;
        border-color: transparent #6422ee transparent transparent;          }

$(function() {
    $( "#menu_samping td" ).mouseover(function() {
        generate_menu(this)
    });
});
function generate_menu(menu){
    $("#testElem, #segitiga").remove();
    $('#menu_samping').after($('<div id="segitiga"></div><div id="testElem">Option inside '+ $(menu).html()+'</div>'));
}
```

and this is my result

[image]

the result that i want is as below :

[image]

and the element will removed after mouse leave the table and additional div element.

can someone help me?? i really need this..
thanks

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7R98p/2/ ?

Comment: almost same, the distance betwen table and div still very far, and the triangles position is not at table option that the mouse over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Av5xM/2/)***</kbd>

*CSS*

```
.inline{
    float:left;
}  

#segitiga {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 12px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
    margin-left:-12px;
}
```

Added a class to all the elements and even changed the css for `segitiga` element...

---

*Just for **reference**, not part of the question*

I guess <kbd>***[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Av5xM/3/)***</kbd> is what you are trying to make.

*Update **1*** <kbd>***[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/Av5xM/6/)***</kbd> **Not a perfect solution, suggestions will be greatly appreciated.**

---

Hope this is what you are looking for...!!

Comment: thanks for the answer,, almost close.. but the element of div and triangles is removed after i out from the table.. how to make the div element is still visible if the mouse is over the div element and table element

Comment: @Hans check the updated answer... I would suggest you to use [this neat method](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimplejQueryDropdowns/) for the solution you are creating...

Comment: tq for the answer.. actualy is already close for my problem.. after i have try your code before i think i have found the way almost same with your code just more simple, you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/hans_sobath/4cDhB/

Comment: @Hans your question has been answered by the code given... This all was additional...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DC39g/1/
basically  `float:left;`
This is a simple solution. 
I have marked the locations that I have changed (only in css).
This might break some alignment around it, in that case ass .

you can use absolute positioning too.
simple example of using absolute in this case would be:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <table style='position:absolute'></table>
    <div style='position:absolute'></div>
</div>
```

but in that case you will have to map all elements exactly according to measurements.

as for the third div (arrow), I will suggest that you use css styling of selected boxes instead.

Anyway, I coded the arrow for you ant it is an update to the above jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/DC39g/2/
Change:

```
var margin=$(menu).position().top+$(menu).height()/2;
$('#menu_samping').after($('<div id="segitiga" style="margin-top:'+margin+'px"></div><div id="testElem">Option inside '+ $(menu).html()+'</div>'));
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the <div id="segitiga"></div> is out if range

Comment: It is in range in the second js fiddle. I ignored it the first time.

Comment: And if you want to move it inside the table, add a negative margin-left equal to the width of <div id="segitiga"></div>.

Comment: ok.. that nice.. but still have one problem.. but the element still visible after the mouse leave the table and div element.. can it invisible if the mouse is out of table and div element?

Comment: A workaround to your issue(not so neat) will be using jquery mouseenter and mouse leave to show or hide the element.  eg: $('#menu_samping).mouseleave(function(){$('#segitiga').hide()});. Note that when using these for testElem you will have to write the code inside generate_menu. It will have to be written after the div has been added to dom so that the functions can be added to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
 $("#menu_samping td").mouseover(function() {
        generate_menu($(this));
    });
    $("#menu_samping td").mouseout(function(){
        remove_div();
    });
});
function generate_menu(menu){
        $('#display_area').html('<div id="segitiga"></div><div id="testElem">Option inside '+ $(menu).html()+'</div>');
    }
    function remove_div(){
        $('#display_area').html('');
    }


<table id='menu_samping' style="float:left">
    <tr>
        <td>Fashion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Electronik</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Food</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Accessories</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="last">Health</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="display_area" style="float:left">

</div>
```

Style of the table and div have to be float left to be displayed beside each other. The table's display option is block as default so the next element you have added is shown under the table element. To avoid this behavior, float left option can be used.